# A hanging lamp makes buzzing sound when on

Tags: lighting

As in the title, I've got a lamp hanging from the ceiling, with a regular E27-screw bulb attached. When I turn the light on, there's a **quiet, buzzing noise**.

The lamp was installed a couple of weeks ago and I am not sure whether the noise was there from the start, as the lamp was not used often.

While the noise is there, the light keeps still, **no flickering**.

**I've tried 2 other bulbs and the problem persists**, which tells me it's either the lamp itself, or the way it was installed.

What do you think this is?

**Photos of the lamp and the base:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post close-up shots of the lamp base with no bulb installed?  This sounds like something's arcing inside...

Comment: Is the lamp on a dimmer?

Comment: @Comintern Nope, no dimmer there.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I updated the post. Hope these photos are any good. Also, sorry, I was AFK.

Comment: Were either of those two other bulbs you tried an incandescent?... Try a different manufacturer's CFL.

Comment: Try the same bulb in a different socket to determine if it is the bulb or the fixture making the buzz. If it is the fixture (it could be the lamp holder or in the ceiling rose) then it very likely needs the connections to be examined for damage and re-made.

Answer (score 1):

Does this lamp have a florescent ballast inside?  This type of lighting will make that hum you are describing.  If so, you can replace the ballast.

Comment: It's fairly apparent that the lamp has a standard bulb socket, and that a CFL is installed.

Comment: @Jonathan727 Why are you replying to me? It's not my question.